# OpenVPN isn't found in FreeBSD 11 -- why?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, freebsd

I'm trying to install OpenVPN on Freebsd 11, but it says it's not found:

```
# pkg install openvpn
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'openvp' have been found in the repositories
```

And

```
uname -a
FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I install it?

Use the correct package name, you appear to be trying to install a package called `openvp`

> pkg install **openvp**
>   ...
>   pkg: No packages available to install matching **'openvp'**

You want to try

```
pkg install openvpn
```

surely.

Comment: That  doesn't work either.

Comment: Hire someone able to handle a keyboard and communicate with others.